# Delete/Unlock the "Historically Locked" How and where do you store your private work/sourcecode?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, locked-question

The question:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35898/how-and-where-do-you-store-your-private-work-sourcecode/
is currently locked, but not deleted, as it is being kept for historical reasons.

It does have a lot of views: 24,601, and 19 upvotes.
It is off-topic as it is asking for everyone's personal opinions.
Which is too discussy for our format.

If asked today, it would probably be closed.
Then downvoted to the point that it is deleted.

Right now, having it locked,
means that you can not down-vote, nor correct  what are now, terribly incorrect/nonoptimal answers.

So the historical lock is damning us to be having blatently poor advise on the site, without the power to correct it.

I don't think this question has enough historical note, to keep it, and let it be wrong for ever.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answers were...abysmal. Yes, it had a lot of views, but I don't see how it can serve as a useful reference based on the answers there.

Comment: Did you delete it?

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος Yes - the question and answer added no value to the site, and only provided a bad example of what we expect from questions and answers.

Comment: Well done, you got a +1!